# style asp button to look like Jquery button with Jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-ui

I don't want to call .button() on my asp:button, I just want to add some classes from the JqueryUI if possible.

I was thinking just adding the class `ui-button` to the asp:button

```
<asp:button class="ui-button" runat="server" id="TrackRequestSearch" Text="Search" 
        onclick="TrackRequestSearch_Click"></asp:button>
```

but this does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: A suitable alternitive would be to use a regular html button and somehow fire the server side on click method, but i'm not sure that can be done easily...

Answer (score 1):

Add CSS style `ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only` to your button.

Answer (score 1):

`ui-button` won't give it a button look exactly. Take a look at what `ui-button` contains:

```
.ui-button {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
padding: 0;
margin-right: .1em;
text-decoration: none !important;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
zoom: 1;
overflow: visible;
}
```

In order to make a jQuery styled button you must add the following to it:

`ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only`

Also load the following CSS: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/base/jquery-ui.css`

Comment: what class is being added on hover?

Comment: It's `.ui-state-hover` and `.ui-state-focus`

Comment: so that would be: `$("#TrackRequestSearch").hover(function () { $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover").addClass("ui-state-focus"); }, function () { $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover").removeClass("ui-state-focus"); });` and how about the style for the click?

Comment: Yes, that's how it should be.

Comment: do you know what the css classes are for the click style?

Answer (score 1):

Use `CssClass` instead of just `class`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <asp:button class="ui-button-text-icon ui-button ui-widget 
    ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" 
    runat="server" id="TrackRequestSearch" Text="Search" 
onclick="TrackRequestSearch_Click"></asp:button>
```

Comment: This doesn't add in the hover style a button has however; so the hover must be an event that is added rather than a css class.

Comment: Or the style when the button is clicked for that matter

Answer (score 0):

Add the following script(s)

```
$(":submit").addClass('ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only'); // All buttons
```

or

```
$('#<%= button1.ClientID %>').addClass('ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only'); // My specific button
```

Tip of the hat to Naveed above for the true classes needed.